Yii2 - How to cache a Database query
I have read many of the posting on this on here, and the Docs, but still am having problems figuring out how to do what I want.
I am using a GridView with dropDown filters. I currently have the following code in my AudioModel to get the selection array:
Public function getFeednameSelect() {
   return ArrayHelper::map(
             Audio::find()
                ->select('feedname')
                ->distinct()
                ->asArray()
                ->all(),
             'feedname', 'feedname'),
}

web\config.php contains
$config = [
    ...
    'components' => [
        ...
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
    ...

The AudioModel currently has over 83k records. I would like to

Probably cache save to a File
Have it rebuild once or twice a day.
It could be linked to changes in a different model Feeds model if count(*) changes.
I'm using the basic-app

This is my first attempt at caching anything.
Thank you.
---UPDATE ---
I have tried the following
    public function getFeednameSelect() {
        $duration = 86400;     // cache query results for 1 day (60*60*24 secs).
        $dependency = [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
            'sql' => 'SELECT MAX(`modifieddatetime`) FROM `feeds`',
        ];

        return ArrayHelper::map(
                        $this->find()
                                ->select('feedname')
                                ->orderBy('feedname')
                                ->distinct()
                                ->asArray()
                                ->cache(15)                         // This works
                                //->cache($duration, $dependency)   // This doesn't
                                ->all(),
                        'feedname', 'feedname');
    }

When I use ->cache($duration, $dependency) I keep getting
Call to a member function evaluateDependency() on array

The $this->find() works. The fieldname and tablename in the 'sql' => statement are correct.

Almost there. I think the only thing you have to change is
$dependency = [
    'class' => 'yii\caching\DbDependency',
    'sql' => 'SELECT MAX(`modifieddatetime`) FROM `feeds`',
];

into
$dependency = new DbDependency();
$dependency->sql = 'SELECT MAX(`modifieddatetime`) FROM `feeds`';

Right now you are passing the dependency as an array, which would explain the error. The dependency needs to be an object, one that extends the caching dependency class.

Works like a champ. Thank You! I could have sworn that I had cut/pasted the array code from somewhere on the Yii website. For others FROM {{%feeds}} works if you are on a shared server.

I found it: /caching-fragment#dependencies

Ah I see, the difference is that the documentation is specifically meant for fragment caching
